# How do I dynamically insert labels with checkboxes in JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp

How do I insert a label tag in my jsp page when new columns are added? Here is the sample code below:

```
<td class="col-1">
    <dsp:getvalueof var="pv_orderview" param="element" idtype="java.lang.Object" />
    <dsp:input type="checkbox" id="${pv_count}" name="ordersCsv" bean="ActivityHistoryFormHandler.csvValues" value="${pv_orderview.orderDate},${pv_orderview.orderId},${pv_orderview.orderTotal},${pv_orderview.status}" />
</td>
```

Comment: What does _"when new columns are added"_ mean? Are they added client-side (in the browser, using JavaScript) or server-side?

Comment: As you can see the checkboxes are added dynamically server side. So I want the labels are added dynamically server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly:

```
<td class="col-1">
    <dsp:getvalueof var="pv_orderview" param="element" idtype="java.lang.Object" />
    <label for="${pv_count}">Label content here</label>
    <dsp:input type="checkbox" id="${pv_count}" name="ordersCsv" bean="ActivityHistoryFormHandler.csvValues" value="${pv_orderview.orderDate},${pv_orderview.orderId},${pv_orderview.orderTotal},${pv_orderview.status}" />
</td>
```

Comment: @Amen: you're welcome. This is, however, a **really** basic thing in writing a JSP; you might want to have a read over a JSP tutorial. http://coreservlets.com/ has very solid material.